# Universal deep link on .Net MAUI iOS is not handled by the app

Tags: ios, deep-linking, maui

I have a .Net MAUI app that needs to open when a user clicks on a link in an email.

The url is from a MS Teams meeting reminder, e.g.

https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_Y2RhZWQzZmsdfdsdsjfdsSSgfdssyOTk4MTJJJJZj%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%226cabcf93-bc92-4081-a34e-768ac7bfd3af%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%224e7b428d-b940-4dab-8de1-07c8f50a2d4e%22%7d

I successfully implemented this for Android, but on an iOS simulator clicking the link opens just a regular Teams website, or (I assume) the Teams app, if it was installed on the simulator.

Here is what I have in Info.plist:

[image]

I expect the user to get options what to open upon clicking the link: either the Teams app, or Teams website, or our app, and execution to come to AppDelegate's OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options).

I guess I am missing some configuration, but can't figure out what that is.

It would be good if I could implement this without creating additional websites, as some solution suggest.

Comment: Does this help? [App Links in Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT It seems to me that this is for custom url rather than universal url... And not clear enough for me.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT You see, in that manual, a custom website is created, and I need to use not my own website link, but a link to an existing MS Teams call link.

Comment: I find a similar issue [[Bug] Unable join ms teams meeting with link from another app in iOS.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/930963/(bug)-unable-join-ms-teams-meeting-with-link-from).

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Not really, there the author is trying to launch the Teams app, and I need to launch my app by clicking on a Teams link.

Comment: Did you mean this? [Xamarin IOS custom URL Scheme not working in iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68827155/xamarin-ios-custom-url-scheme-not-working-in-ios-14)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT That question is talking about custom URL Scheme, but I need to open my app upon clicking on MS Teams link rather than my own.

Comment: Then your app and Teams app use the same url scheme?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Yes! That is why on Android, when the link is clicked, I am asked if I want to open the Teams app or our own app. I was told that iOS does not allow this, unlike Android. But if iOS knows that it should open MS Teams upon clicking on such a link, maybe it is possible to register our app somehow with Apple to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think we cannot do that. See Apple docs: [Register your URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app#Register-your-URL-scheme)

> If multiple apps register the same scheme, the app the system targets is undefined. There’s no mechanism to change the app or to change the order apps appear in a Share sheet.

That means we cannot determine which app to open at runtime.

For more info, you could also refer to this SO issue [Multiple apps with the same URL Scheme - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130442/multiple-apps-with-the-same-url-scheme-ios).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Of course, automatically iOS cannot determine what to open, but why can't it ask the user, like Android does it? Thank you for the links!